Azure function app using Python: Issue in parsing a JSON string in request body
I am trying to parse a very simple flat JSON in Azure Function App using Python. This JSON is coming as a POST request. Below is the complete Azure Function App code:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json
#from urllib.parse import parse_qs

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="functionAppTest",methods=[func.HttpMethod.POST])
def functionAppTest(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
  logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
  res_b = str(req.get_body())
  logging.info(f"Request Bytes: {res_b}")
  print(res_b)

  if res_b:
    logging.info(f"request transformed:{json.loads(res_b)}")
    print(json.loads(res_b))
    return func.HttpResponse(
      json.loads(res_b).values(),
      status_code=400)
  else:
    return func.HttpResponse("Not Working!")

Since this is a POST request, while testing I am passing a JSON string E.g. {"name":"Azure"}.
And it is giving the below the error:
Exception: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Indicating that json.loads() is not getting any string.
But from logging.info() , I can clearly see that Request Bytes: b'{"name":"Azure"}'
I feel it might be a trivial issue, but unfortunately I am not able to decipher.
What I am missing above?

The issue you are encountering with the json.loads() function is due to the way you are converting the request body to a string. The str(req.get_body()) call returns a string representation of the bytes object, which includes the byte string's prefix b'. This is why json.loads() is failing to parse it as valid JSON.
Code :
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import json

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="functionAppTest", methods=[func.HttpMethod.POST])
def functionAppTest(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    
    try:
        req_body = req.get_json()
        logging.info(f"Request JSON: {req_body}")

        return func.HttpResponse(
            json.dumps(req_body),
            status_code=200,
            mimetype="application/json"
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(f"JSON decoding error: {e}")
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Invalid JSON format",
            status_code=400
        )

Postman Output :
I sent the post request successfully in Postman as follows:
http://localhost:7071/api/functionAppTest

{
  "name": "Azure"
}

Output :
The HTTP trigger function with a post request ran successfully as follows:
 *  Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate && func host start 

Found Python version 3.10.11 (py).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5198 Commit hash: N/A  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.21.1.20667

[2024-05-25T10:34:36.163Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        functionAppTest: [POST] http://localhost:7071/api/functionAppTest

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-05-25T10:34:44.214Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '00000000xxxxxxxxxxxxx'.
[2024-05-25T10:36:52.955Z] Executing 'Functions.functionAppTest' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=20e41f79xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
[2024-05-25T10:36:53.107Z] Request JSON: {'name': 'Azure'}
[2024-05-25T10:36:53.107Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[2024-05-25T10:36:53.259Z] Executed 'Functions.functionAppTest' (Succeeded, Id=20e41f79xxxxxxxxxxxxx, Duration=330ms)


Yes eventually I also ended up using json.dumps() before this answer came. Many thanks anyway.
